# Ionic refresh view

Tags: ionic-framework, refresh, page-refresh, ionic-view

I need to refresh my app view every time I open the view
Anyone know how to refresh the ionic view?
The answer I found is using ion-refresher and cache view 
But ion-refresher just like to use for pull to refresh 
Do there got any other method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In the view's controller, you can listen to the [$ionicView.enter or $ionicView.beforeEnter](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/) events to listen to when a view is entered.

```
$scope.$on( "$ionicView.enter", function(event) {
    $scope.refresh();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an atribute in the HTML:

```
<ion-view cache-view="false" view-title="My Title!">
  ...
</ion-view>
```

Or, in your `app.js`:

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
   cache: false,
   url : '/myUrl',
   templateUrl : 'my-template.html'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

with this line in your stard app can save time put cache-view="false" in all your views, so imagin you have in your projects 50 views and need to add this tag, a easiet an elegant way is use this line to your app do not stored the view and every time it get focus it refrefreshing automatically.

$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);

Hope, it help you.